# Spark kafka restart on not getting the offset within range

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

We are storing the kafka offset in DB for checkpointing. This helps in zero message loss when restarting our application.

There is a scenario where when we restart spark application the offset is not in kafka (due to being wiped out because of upgrade or running in docker). In this scenario spark app throws the error

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: numRecords must not be negative
```

We would like to restart app and read from latest offset in such case.

```
try{
 KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder, (String, String)](
    ssc, kafkaParams, fromOffset, msgHandler)
} catch {case ex: Exception => {
KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String,
    StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topicsSet)
 }
}
```

Adding try/catch and starting from latest offset is not helping here. Since the error happens in the executor. Is there a way to handle this from spark driver?